# Bash while condition: Is my test correct? Infinity loop entails

Tags: bash, shell-script

as I have already explained in my other thread [While statement: Cannot get compound of multiple conditions to work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652780/while-statement-cannot-get-compound-of-multiple-conditions-to-work) I am trying to parse the input arguments in a `recursive descent` fashion.

Sadly, the thread, although the participants were by far more knowledgable than me and gave good advice, the problem still persists.

Also I poked around myself some further in the console with no avail.

I have following two `while` statements in my script, which are problematic, because obviously the `endOfInput` function has no influence on ending the while loop.

I would poke around and sometimes it wouldn't even enter the loop.

So the outer `while-statement` is the following:

```
while [ $current_token_index -le $ARGC ] && [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$ ]] || ! [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{,2})*$ ]]; do
```

Also, again, here is the inner `while-statement`

```
while [[ "$current_token_index" -le "$ARGC" ]] && [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{,2})*$ ]]; do
```

Also the helper methods:

```
isWord? () {
    local pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$"
    if [[ $1 =~ $pattern ]]; then
        echo true
    else
        echo false
    fi
}

isVersionNumber? () {
    local pattern="^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{,2})*$"
    if [[ $1 =~ $pattern ]]; then
        echo true
    else
        echo false
    fi
}

EO_ARGS=false

function endOfInput? {
 if [ $current_token_index -ge $ARGC ]; then
    EO_ARGS=true
 fi
 echo $EO_ARGS
}
```

Additionally the `eat!` function that gets us the next token from a copy of the positional

```
eat! () {
        current_token=${ARGV[$current_token_index]}
        ((current_token_index += 1))
        
        current_char=${current_token:0:1}
}
```

And above that I declare

```
# as set by eat!()
current_token=""
current_char=""

current_token_index=0
curent_char_index=0
```

My question refers to the possibility, that the `endOfInput` (originally: `endOfInput?` but I deleted the `?` as I learned, in bash it has a wildcard meaning which can lead to problems. In Ruby you can choose most special characters as identifiers with no problems. Obviously there are many caveats in bash if you come from other programming languages) ... so that the truth value of `endOfInput` function is not evaluated correctly via multiple definitions of the function together with different testing or comparing syntax in a while-statement with its own exigences towards evaluating whether or not a condition holds or not. So there are three things in the equation that together are responsible for the formulation of the conditional constellation.

The problem with the `while` loop heads as posted above are that either they aren't entered or they don't stop. Depending on how I test `endOfInput` or how I group it.

If I replace `! endOfInput && ...` just by `! false && ...` for instance the while loop would be entered, in the other case not.

This is why I conjecture that there must be a problem with the function. It is not correctly evaluated. The problem may be 1) the definition of `endOfInput`, or 2) how it gets tested that is,

- 2.1 with *what test* (things like `-eq`, string comparison like `=`, arithmetic operators like `==`)
- 2.2 *what* is tested. I.e.

  - 2.2.1 A string "true"/"false"
  - 2.2.2 `true` and `false` as literals
  - 2.2.3 `0` for `true` and `1` for `false`
- 3 How is this value correctly returned?

  - 3.1 by `return`
  - 3.2 by `exit`
  - 3.3 by `echo`
- 4 by what testing construct is the returned value compared to something else?

  - 4.1 none, just executing the function
  - 4.2 brackets (`[` or `[[` command)
  - 4.3 arithmetic parentheses `((...))`
  - 4.4 arithmetic expansion `$((...))`
  - 4.5 one or multiple of those combined

So please take a look at the definition of `endOfInput` and how it is used in the head of the `while` statement. What could be the problem, why there is an infinity loop? I mean, the other two functions like `isWord?` do work.

How should my function definition of `endOfInput` and how should the testing and concatenation of it in the `while` statement should look like such that it is correctly evaluated?

Edit: ilkkachu wanted me to post a "minimal, complete and verifiable example"

I hope the following is sufficient.

First I call `get_installed_gems_with_versions` to get all installed gems and their versions in an associative array. Now I have the global associative array `installedGems`.

Then I want to **parse** the option --gems by calling `parse_gems_with_versions`, which in turn calls `parseGemVersions` in order to parse a selection of the installed gems and their version into `$chosenGemVersions`

I let away the code of some tests that are relevant to the parsing part but not to the current problem if the not working while loop.

So here is the code

```
get_installed_gems_with_versions () {

unset installedGems
declare -Ag installedGems

local last_key=""
local values=""

  while read -r line; do
  
    line=${line##*/}
    
    KEY="${line%-*}"

        VALUE="${line##*-}"
        
        if [ -z ${installedGems[$KEY]+x} ]; then

            echo "key $KEY doesn't yet exist."
            echo "append value $VALUE to key $KEY"
            
            installedGems[$KEY]="$VALUE"
            continue
            
        else
            echo "key already exists"
            echo "append value $VALUE to $KEY if not already exists"
            installedGems[$KEY]="${installedGems[$KEY]} $VALUE"
            echo "result: ${installedGems[$KEY]}"
        fi 
        
    done < <(find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "^${directory}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*-[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,3}){,3}\$")

 }

parseGemVersions () {
    
    local version_list
    
    declare -Ag chosenGemVersions
    
    while [[ "$current_token_index" -le "$ARGC" ]] && [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{,2})*$ ]]; do
    
            if versionOfGemInstalled? $gem $current_token; then
            
                if [ -z ${chosenGemVersions[$gem]+x} ]; then
                
                    chosenGemVersions[$gem]=$current_token
                # continue
                else
                    chosenGemVersions[$gem]="${chosenGemVersions[$gem]} $current_token"
                fi
                
            else
                parsing_error! "While parsing function $FUNCNAME, current version number $current_token is not installed!"
            fi
            
            echo "result: ${chosenGemVersions[$gem]}"
        
        eat!
            
    done

}

parse_gems_with_versions () {
# option --gems 
# --gems gem-name-1 1.1.1 1.2.1 1.2.5 gem-name-2 latest gem-name-3 ...

    unset gem
    unset chosenGemVersions

    gem=""
    declare -Ag chosenGemVersions

        while [ $current_token_index -le $ARGC ] && [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$ ]] || ! [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{,2})*$ ]]; do
        
                if isWord? $current_token && [ ! "$current_token" = "latest" ]; then
                        if isWord? $current_token; then
                            if gemInstalled? $current_token; then
                                # We can conjecture that the word token is in fact a gems' name
                                gem=$current_token
                                
                                local version_list
                                
                                if isWord? $current_token && [ "$current_token" = "latest" ]; then
                                    version_list=(${installedGems[$gem]})
                                    chosenGemVersions[$gem]="${version_list[${#version_list} -1]}"
                                else
                                    # gets list chosenGemVersions
                                    parseGemVersions
                                fi
                            else
                                parsing_error! "Gem $token_name not installed!"
                            fi
    
                        fi
             else
                parsing_error! "While parsing function $FUNCNAME, "latest" is not a gemname!"
             fi
            
            eat!
            
        done
}
```

Comment: Why the two downvotes and the closing wish? What exactly is wrong with my question? I clearly describe a clear problem. The while statement in compound with its' conditions goes into an infinite loop. I can't explain why. Where did I do something wrong?

Comment: You don't have a function called `endOfInput`, the code you showed only has a function called `endOfInput?`. Which ever it is, it wouldn't affect the conditions in those two `while` loops, because neither of them seems to a) call the function, nor b) use the variable `EO_ARGS` set by the function.

Comment: As for what the downvotes are for, take a look at what a "minimal, complete and verifiable example" (or "minimal and reproducible exampe") is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349789/how-do-i-create-a-minimal-complete-verifiable-example That is to say, _show the code, **the whole code**_, _drop the unnecessary parts_ and the irrelevant chatter, and _tell **exactly** what it is you're trying to achieve_

Comment: Part of what is needed for a _complete_ example is the whole script, in full, and the command used to run it, *and* the inputs to it. That the being the stuff the reader needs to run your code. Also, you need to show the outputs you _expect_ to get, because, well, how else would anyone other than know what it is you want to get. Here, you only show some functions, but nothing about how they're called. We can't know what your script contains.

Comment: Also, if you want someone to look at what your script is doing with the arguments, you need to tell what it's _supposed_ to do, _in English_. You wrote here that "If I replace ! endOfInput && ... just by ! false && ... for instance the while loop would be entered, in the other case not.", which hints at `endOfinput` not doing what you expect it to do, so you might want to look there. (Well, minus the fact that your code here doesn't contain a line with `! endOfInput &&`...)

Comment: I had the question mark removed. But however, the function is out of the equation anyway because I substituted it for a bracket test which should give correct exit codes or whatever to the while loop. And the **relevant parts** are the while loops as posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126108/discussion-between-ilkkachu-and-von-spotz).

Comment: In the last thread I was indeed more unsure what I should post at all or how I should ask. I think I made it better in this thread apart from accidentally posting the old named version of `endOfInput`

And I **did convey** what it is what I want to do. I am parsing the arguments of a script "in the fashion of" a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: Hello ilkkachu, is that sufficient?

Comment: ok, looking at that part you added, it's easy to tell it's not a complete program, because it just defines functions, but doesn't show the main program that would call them. So, the reader still can't tell what inputs it takes. In the least, the code is missing the `eat!` function. Now, that one we can look at, since you did include it separately, and we can see it sets `current_token`, which is a major which shellcheck.net notes that is used but not set in your code. But then `eat!` uses an array called `ARGV`, and nowhere is it shown what that is.

Comment: At this point, I'm just going to stop repeating myself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is mainly in misunderstanding boolean type in shell scripts.

You can basically replace the first helper functions with these:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit

is_word ()
{
    local pattern='^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$'
    [[ "$1" =~ $pattern ]]
}

is_version_number ()
{
    local pattern='^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{,2})*$'
    [[ "$1" =~ $pattern ]]
}

# testing is_word ()
if is_word 'bla01'; then
    echo IS word
else
    echo NOT word
fi

# testing is_version_number ()
if is_version_number '1.1'; then
    echo IS version number
else
    echo NOT version number
fi
```

You see, do not try to echo true/false or anything, the test command (`[..]` or `[[..]]`) itself returns proper boolean (actually integer), never use your own true/false constructs.

Additionally, always use ShellCheck (https://www.shellcheck.net/) to bullet-proof your scripts, or debug them.

Good habit also is using `set -o nounset` (`set -u`) and `set -o errexit` (`set -e`).

---

With the updated version of your question, I see you are used to C programming probably. There is no `$ARGC`, nor `$ARGV` in shell scripts. Use these instead:

- `ARGC` (argument count): `"$#"`
- `ARGV` (argument array): `"$@"`

---

For example, you could do this:

```bash
eat_args ()
{
    for arg in "$@"; do
        current_char=${arg:0:1}
        echo "$current_char"
    done
}
eat_args "$@"
```

which does not make much sense to me, as it prints the first letter of each given argument. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: It  won't even enter the second statement: `while [ $current_token_index -le $ARGC ] && isVersionNumber? "$current_token"; do` or with `while [ $current_token_index -le $ARGC ] && [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{,2})*$ ]]; do`

Comment: so you are saying I can't / shouldn't write own testing functions? Then the only alternative is either string comparison or brackets, right?

Comment: thanks for the link. Seems like a helpful tool !

Comment: How can I write correct helper functions for conditional tests then? Also, why does the while loop run infinite?  `while [[ "$current_token_index" -le "$ARGC" ]] && [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{,2})*$ ]]; do` an `echo` shows that `$current_token_index` is 1201 when I hit CTRL+C and `$ARGC` is 4

Comment: @vonspotz Sure you can write your own testing functions, but you have to be aware that their _exit value_ is evaluated in the boolean test, not their output. If you don't just want to use the exit value of the last statement in the function, you can still put in an explicit `return` with the right value wherever it suits you.

Comment: The first thing to learn about boolean types in shell scripts is that there are no boolean types in shell scripts... There's only strings and exit statuses, and the latter aren't much of a type since you can't store them in variables.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak - Regarding your update. I did those copies on purpose. Because it's the only way my script would work, because I couldn't `shift` the script arguments from inside other functions. So I am working on the copies which I called accordingly to the common terminology. Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

The solution is grouping the conditions connected through the `||` operator.

```
while [[ $current_token_index -le $ARGC ]] && { [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$ ]] || ! [[ "$current_token" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{,2})*$ ]]; }; do
```